# Assigning template tag in base template

Tags: django, django-templates

I want to get a value in my base.html template which every other template extends. Here's my custom tag code:

```
#my_tags.py
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag # or assignment tag, doesn't matter
def is_true():
    return True
```

And when used in base.html as such:

```
<!-- base.html -->
{% load my_tags %}
{% is_true %}
```

The string "True" is printed. However if I try to do this

```
<!-- base.html -->
{% load my_tags %}
{% is_true as my_var %}
<h1>{{my_var}}</h1>
```

I get TypeError at /'WSGIRequest' object does not support item assignment. Following the stack trace it appears that "context" just isn't available at base.html. If I put this in any of the templates extending base, I can assign the variable and print it as I desire. Assignment is important because I need to condition on the value returned. Is this a known limitation that `as` doesn't work in a base template? How can I get the returned value in base.html?

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with the location of the tag. It looks like you are confused because one of your views also passes a variable of the same name (`is_true`) as a context variable.

Comment: i am not sure but try using {% with myvar = is_true %}

Comment: @Selcuk is_true is just for my minimal example. It could just as well be `function_abc`. Is a different context passed to the "parent" template? If we look at django's source the error comes attempting to [assign a context](https://github.com/django/django/blob/a7c6c705e82bfb9f061f35d38c2a6184dae52cd4/django/template/library.py#L194) when there's a target variable.